# validations in textbox in vb.net

Tags: textbox

i have a textbox wherein the user is required to enter amount.i want to know the way to put a validation on the key press event so that the user might not enter more than one decimal point i.e user is allowed to enter values like 99.999 only not like 99...22
plz suggest some property or method to do this??

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are a good way to do that!

Check out:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

This might be the regex you are looking for:

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?
```

Comment: its done now..i hv used the isnumeric function.bt i m getting another problem..
i want the user to enter as many digits before decimal point but only two digits after the decimal point..like 123.45 or 12.67 or 4566.67?
how to do that?

Comment: or consider using a masked textbox